# A bad error in PHP

Tags: php, html, login-script

I created a login page confirmation but when I want to login I find this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u133082736/public_html/login.php on line 14

This is my code :

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_POST) {
        require_once 'config.php';
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];     
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
            or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM email_activation WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s') AND password='%s'");
            mysql_real_escape_string($username),
            mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)));
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if($count == 1) {
            $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $query = sprintf("UPDATE email_activation SET last_login = NOW() WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s') AND password = '%s'",
                mysql_real_escape_string($username),
                mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)));
            mysql_query($query);
            $query = sprintf("SELECT is_admin FROM email_activation WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('%s') AND password='%s'",
                mysql_real_escape_string($username),
                mysql_real_escape_string(md5($password)));
            echo $query
            list($is_admin) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            if($is_admin == 1) {
                header('Location:admin.php');           
            } else {
                header('Location:home.php');                
            }
        } else {    ?>
<span style='color:red'>Error: that username and password combination does not match any currently within our database.</span>
<?php   }
    }
?>
```

Please help me understand what caused the error and how to prevent it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Comment: Do your own debugging by changing `$result = mysql_query($query);` to `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`. Your query is failing, which is why you are getting that error message, so you need to figure out what is wrong with your query.

Comment: The same problem ! :(

Answer (score 0):

If your Query returns nothing the parameter is empty and you get the error message mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 , you should debug your query. I would sugguest that you try `echo $query` and see the result of that, that would be a good starting point.

[Link to mysql_fetch_row() documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: Okay, please do remember to accept answers if they helped you.

Comment: Yes ! + can you please see again in my code and try to tell me what's the parse error there ?? i'm a newbie in PHP !

Comment: I have changed it !

Comment: Yes ! please see on it and let me know what's the error

Comment: I dont understand what list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($result); is about, Please try   `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ); ` instead of   `$result = mysql_query($query);
        list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($result); `

Comment: i did it , but i got another error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in /home/u133082736/public_html/login.php on line 8)

Comment: You cant use " or die ()"  like that, or is the same as || which is used in if statemets, you need to use and if else statement and not " or die ".

Comment: Ah Okay , Thank you for your helpful answers , and sorry for my lot questions !

Comment: No worries were here to help :)